# Eclipse SQL file editor - how to use bind variables

Tags: sql, database, eclipse, editor

Does Eclipse (I'm using Mars.2 Release 4.5.2) support bind variables in SQL File Editor? E.g. can I write

```
select * from contacts where id=:contact_id
```

and have Eclipse asking for :contact_id value before execution?

Comment: Please specify, what you have been reseaching on this problem so far.

Comment: I'm able to create file with *.sql extension (in Java project), open it in "SQL File Editor" and execute it against the database. If SQL query contains named bind variables, Eclipse ignores them and sends query to the execution "as is" which produces database error.